# I need assistance with an Auto Alert View with actions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

Okay so when a user first launches my app I want an Alert View that will pop up with 2 choices. Im using this method below:

```
- (void) displayWelcomeScreen
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *alreadyRun = @"already-run";
    if ([prefs boolForKey:alreadyRun])
        return;
    [prefs setBool:YES forKey:alreadyRun];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"…"
        message:@"…"
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

When I first launch the app no Alert View pops up. Am I doing something wrong? BTW I want it to display only on the first launch of the app. It must not display any other time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried that now but no luck it still did not show.

Comment: Just to clarify you must set the delegate in the .h file write?

Comment: how did you set the delegate? show here.

Comment: Where you are calling your displayWelcomeScreen method?

Comment: I used <AlertViewDelegate> in viewcontroller.h file

Comment: Sorry I meant <UIAlertViewDelegate>

Comment: Im not too sure what you mean by calling. Please explain

Comment: I mean you must be calling your method like [self displayWelcomeScreen]; somewhere in your viewcontroller.m

Comment: Its probably where you're calling it

Comment: You may be calling it in viwDidLoad or somewhere else.

Comment: Im calling it just below viewDidLoad

Comment: Are you doing like this inside viewDidLoad:- (void)viewDidLoad{[self displayWelcomeScreen];}

Comment: Nope Im doing it just after the } of viewDidLoad

Comment: So you are just defining your method not calling it.Just check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(void)viewDidLoad{

NSLog(@"In viewDidLoad");
[self displayWelcomeScreen];

}
```

in displayWelcomeScreen write code:

```
- (void) displayWelcomeScreen
{
    NSLog(@"In displayWelcomeScreen");
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *alreadyRun = @"already-run";
    if ([prefs boolForKey:alreadyRun])
        return;
    [prefs setBool:YES forKey:alreadyRun];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"…"
        message:@"…"
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

and check whether in console it is displaying In displayWelcomeScreen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these. I just made some alterations to your code.

```
- (void) displayWelcomeScreen
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"alreadyRun"])
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        [prefs setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"alreadyRun"];
        [prefs synchronize];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"…"
        message:@"…"
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Comment: try putting some breakpoint in the starting of the function and check the flow of control. Then we can figure out from where the control deviates.

Comment: Im new to xcode so I not too confident with breakpoints. Ive always wanted to use them though.

Comment: You can add breakpoints by just cliking above on the line number of each code line (on the side bar shown on the left to code which shows the line number). Or please try to insert some NSLogs randomly in the code and check how the control flow works over there. If the NSLog() executed, you can get the message printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

in you appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, add something like this

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![defaults boolForKey:@"everLaunched"]) {
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"everLaunched"];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"firstLaunch"];
}
else{
    [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"firstLaunch"];
}
```

to check if you need to display welcome message:

```
 - (void) displayWelcomeScreen
 {
  if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) 
         {
          NSLog(@"I should display alert view now with two selections");
          //what to you want to to here now? show alert view? with two choices?
          //you might want to remember the selected choice from user
         }
   else  {
         NSLog(@"the user already made his choice, this is not a first launch");
         //what do you want to do here now? show home screen? let the user use the app? 
         //the user has already made his choice
         }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the completed code for the displayWelcomeScreen ? Im a little confused.

Comment: @James I edited the code. add comment when you encounter problem

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what I did. It still wont show though. I must be making a mistake somewhere

Comment: I uninstalled the app but no alert view. Is there a specific location im meant to put the displayWelcomeScreen

Comment: @James I edited the code. i suppose you calll displayWelcomeScreen when the user is about to use the app, did you add the first code snippet in your app Delegate>?

Comment: Yes Ive I added the first snippet in the app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions